# Copying files task as a specific user Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, file-copying

I'm trying to copy a directory from a folder to a destination (the destination is a shared folder on the network).
How may I perform this action with the credential of a specific user? (I've tried with a Powershel script using cmdlet New-PSDrive but that didn't work for me)

The powershell I've tried:

```bsh
$securePassword= ConvertTo-SecureString "pwd" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $securePassword)
$source="path"

New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "path" -Credential $creds
Copy-Item $source -Destination Y:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
Remove-PSDrive Y
```

Comment: Do you want to do the copy with the second machine user?

Comment: Just perform the whole process with a specific credential (not default)

Comment: What do you mean process? the whole pipeline? or the copy process?

Comment: it blocks only on the copy task not the whole pipline

Comment: In the copy try to use "Windows Machine File Copy" as my answer below.

Comment: It's a shared folder on the network, I'm updating the post...

Comment: Have to check -- this is running on a self-hosted agent or in the cloud?

Comment: self-hosted with full access and rights

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task "Windows Machine File Copy":

```
- task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
  inputs:
    SourcePath: 'C:/test'
    MachineName: '10.10.10.10' # or 'mymachine01'
    AdminUserName: 'domain/myUser'
    AdminPassword: 'password'
    TargetPath: 'D:/test'
```

So now the copy to the second machine will be the credntials your provided.

Comment: Oh ok, can you share what did you try with powershell and which error you get? and, you still can use this task without the UNC path instead of the regular copy.

Comment: $securePassword= ConvertTo-SecureString "pwd" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $securePassword)
$source="path"

New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "path" -Credential $creds
Copy-Item $source -Destination Y:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
Remove-PSDrive Y

Comment: The error is: New-PSDrive : The network name cannot be found

Comment: It's hard to understand in the comment, please edit the question. and did you try my solution?

Comment: Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination. The network name cannot be found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194888/discussion-between-shayki-abramczyk-and-gsmida).